# Convert number to date format in PowerBI

Tags: date, powerbi, powerquery

I am having struggle to convert a number format to a date/datetime format in PowerBI ( in the query editor).

The rowformat in csv looks like this (german timezone):

```
202007201155180
201912012200001
```

which would lead to:

```
20.07.2020 11:55:18
01.12.2019 22:20:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use division ([`Number.IntegerDivide`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-integerdivide)) and modulo ([`Number.Mod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/number-mod)) to calculate the date parts (year, month, day, hour, etc.) and construct a datetime value ([`#datetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/sharpdatetime)) in a [custom column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-add-custom-column), e.g. like this:

```
#datetime(
    Number.IntegerDivide([num], 100000000000), // Year
    Number.IntegerDivide(Number.Mod([num], 100000000000), 1000000000), // Month
    Number.IntegerDivide(Number.Mod([num], 1000000000), 10000000), // Day
    Number.IntegerDivide(Number.Mod([num], 10000000), 100000), // Hour
    Number.IntegerDivide(Number.Mod([num], 100000), 1000), // Minute
    Number.IntegerDivide(Number.Mod([num], 1000), 10) // Second
    )
```

This will give you a new datetime column:

[image]

But note, that `201912012200001` is not `01.12.2019 12:20:00` as you said, but `01.12.2019 22:00:00`, and the last digit is not converted, so the fraction of the second (tenth of the second) is lost.